# No me encuentra la ruta vista-controlador en Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, rutas

Estoy aprendiendo Laravel y tengo un problema con la ruta vista-controlador y una plantilla que contiene un formulario, al intentar entrar en la ruta de productos/create me da un error 500. También me da error si intento guardar datos con el método post.

Archivo web.php

```
 <?php
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\ProductoController;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome'); 
    });
    
    Route::get('productos',[ProductoController::class, 'index']);
    
    Route::get('productos/create',[ProductoController::class, 'create']);
    
    Route::get('productos/{producto}',[ProductoController::class, 'show']);
    Route::post('productos', [ProductoController::class, 'store']);
```

Archivo del controlador ProductoController.php

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    
    class ProductoController extends Controller {
      public function index()
      {
        return view('productos.index');
      }
      
      public function show($nombre)
      {
        return view('productos/show', ['producto' => $nombre]); 
      }
      
      public function create()
        {
          return view('productos/create');
        }
      public function store(Request $request){
        print_r($request->all());
  }
    };
```

Archivo del template, template.blade.php dentro de la carpeta layout que este en la carpeta views

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>@yield('title')</title>


  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  
</head>
<body>
  <main>

  <div class="container py-4">

  @yield('content')

  <footer class="pt-3 mt-4 text-muted border-top">
    Codigos de programación
  </footer>
  </div>
  </main>
  
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Archivo create.blade.php con el formulario que metemos en el template

```
@extends('layout/template') 

@section('title', 'Nuevo producto')

@section('content')

<form action="{{ url('/productos') }}" method="post">
    @csrf

<div class="mb-3">
  <label for="nombre" class="form-label">Nombre</label>
  <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
  <label for="precio" class="form-label">Precio</label>
  <input type="text" name="precio" id="precio" class="form-control">
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>

</form>

@endsection
```

Estoy siguiendo un video del curso y no veo el error por ningún lado. Agradezco su ayuda, si necesitan algun otro archivo o dato, solo indiquenme cual y lo mostraré. Gracias.

He intentado poner el formulario directamente en el archivo create, sin el template y sin el controlador, con una ruta directa a views productos.create y si que me sale el formulario, pero necesito hacerlo a través del controlador.
He intentado seguir el curso llamando al create sin el controlador y al hacer el metodo post para enviar los datos me vuelve a salir el error 500. Ya no se como continuar.

Answer (score 1):

La carpeta layout debe existir dentro de views. En caso contrario, en lugar de `@extends('layout/template')` deberías escribir `@extends('layouts/template')`, que es la carpeta que trae por defecto Laravel para los layouts.

En cualquier caso, el error 500 puede venir de una configuración errónea del servidor. Aquí ya depende del entorno de desarrollo que estés usando: sail, homestead, laragon...

Otra opción:

En la documentación oficial de Laravel 9 se usa el carácter "." en lugar de "/" para acceder a las plantillas que están dentro de una carpeta. Prueba con lo siguiente:

@extends('layout.template')

[Solución]
Tú código a mí me funciona y me muestra el formulario. Uso Laravel Sail en Ubuntu, así que me inclino a pensar que es un problema de tu entorno de desarrollo.

Saludos.

Comment: Si, la carpeta layout está dentro de views, el servidor funciona bien con todas las rutas, estoy usando artisan serve, pero en apache me pasa lo mismo.

Comment: Jesus Arribi, no es conveniente que generes dos respuestas para la misma pregunta (te lloverán votos negativos), siempre puedes editar tu respuesta y hacer los cambios pertinentes. (yo eliminaría la de arriba).

Comment: Mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para evitar votos negativos y/o que tu repuesta sea eliminada.
Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtengas una mejor respuesta, y de paso evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada, y de paso, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: De acuerdo. Gracias por tus sugerencias.

Comment: Gracias Jesús, he probado todo lo que me dices y no hay manera, me sigue dando el mismo error, en el devtools solo me dice que tengo un error 500 en la pestaña de red, pero no consigo encontrar el error. La verdad es que no soy de backend, soy frontend y me han pedido que aprenda las bases de Laravel,  pero si empieza a fallar el servidor me pierdo bastante. Por lo que me dices el código está correcto y el fallo esta el servidor.

Comment: ¿Qué entorno de desarrollo estás usando? Laravel Sail, Laragon, homestead...

Comment: Diría que Laragon, pero no recuerdo. Estoy buscando la manera de poder acceder a esa información en mi ubuntu y no la encuentro. También tengo xampp y tampoco me funciona el código. Como IDE utilizo Visual.

Comment: No creo que sea esto pero revisando el código del controller veo que te falta importar la clase Request: use Illuminate\Http\Request;
Prueba a ver...

Comment: Otra cosa, ¿la vista create.blade.php la tienes dentro de una carpeta productos dentro de la carpeta views, verdad?

Comment: La clase si la tengo importada, al editar la pregunta se me olvido ponerlo, ademas que ya fallaba antes de hacer la petición post. Por otra parte la vista create.blade está dentro de la carpeta de productos que está dentro de views. Gracias por el interes Jesús, no se si dejarlo ya de lado y empezar otro curso que no me tantos problemas.

Comment: Tú código a mí me funciona y me muestra el formulario. Uso Laravel Sail en Ubuntu, así que me inclino a pensar que es un problema de tu entorno de desarrollo.

Comment: Ok, gracias Jesús, voy a probar Laravel Sail. Ya te dire si funciona, si es asi, podrás editar tu respuesta y te la validare, así si le pasa a otra persona ya sabrá que sucede. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Lo conseguí, me toco instalar docker de nuevo y después de muchas pruebas parece que funciona. Gracias de nuevo Jesús.

Comment: Me alegro! Ánimo. Laravel es una excelente opción para backend y la curva de aprendizaje no es muy dura :-)